# How to force creation of default sequence constructor when other constructors are present?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default

Since C++11, we have this great feature that allows us to avoid explicit constructor creation for all the little classes like:

```
class A
{
public:
  A() = default;
  A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {} // bloat
  int x = 0, y = 0;
};
..
A a(1,2);
```

So we can write it like this now:

```
class A
{
public:
  int x = 0, y = 0;
};
..
A a{1,2}; // using the sequence constructor created by the compiler, great
```

The problem arises, when I have also other constructor that I want to use, for example:

```
class A
{
public:
  A() = default;
  A(Deserialiser& input) : a(input.load<int>()), b(input.load<int>()) {}
  int x = 0, y = 0;
};
...
A a{1, 2}; // It doesn't work now, as there is another constructor explicitly specified
```

The question is, how do I force the compiler to create the default sequence constructor?

Comment: I'm not use what you mean by the term "sequence constructor", but I think you mean a normal constructor taking an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)? Then no there's no way to automatically generate such a constructor that will do the right thing. And as noted in my answer, it's not what's happening in the second example anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference with the second example is that you're doing [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

With the first and third examples, aggregate initialization is no longer possible (because then the class has user-defined constructors).

With the first example then the two-argument constructor is called. With the third example no suitable constructor can be found and you will get an error.

---

Note: In C++11 aggregate initialization would not be possible with the second example either, since C++11 didn't allow for non-static members being initialized inline. That limitation was removed in C++14. (See the above linked reference for more information.)

Comment: Hm, ok I get it. So the answer is, that it is not possible. But I have to say, that the condition for it to be a pod type seems to be completely unnecessary in my view.

Comment: @nwp It can most certainly be done, but one need to add a suitable constructor.

Comment: Just for clarification: having a *user-defined constructor* prevents the type for being a *POD* type.

Comment: Yes, but why would it have to be POD? I don't see any reason for it. It would be the same as not creating for examaple copy constructor when it is not pod.

Comment: @kovarex as already said in the answer: if the type is not a POD, you can't use aggregate initialization.

Comment: @眠りネロク What would you say to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19723a0ca6ad90bd)?

Comment: @nwp You're correct in that `A` is not a POD type in the second example, as it have no [trivial default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor) (because the members are initialized). I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you name a constructor, you remove all other auto-generated names.

By naming `A(Deserialiser&)`, you lost the auto-genrated `A(int, int)`

On way to express the constructors would be:

```
class A
{
public:
  A() : A(0, 0) {}   // <- set default values here
  A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
  A(Deserialiser& input) : x(input.load<int>()), y(input.load<int>()) {}
  int x, y;
};
```

One approach to retain the aggregate initialisation would be to decouple the serialisation from the object itself.

```
template<class Type> struct type_tag {};

class A
{
public:
    A()  = default;

    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

auto deserialise(Deserialiser& input, type_tag<A>)
{
    return A { input.load<int>(), input.load<int>() };
}
```

Comment: Avoiding to write the constructors manually was the whole point of this question.

Comment: @kovarex Forgive me. I guess the answer is, "it's not possible".
Perhaps construct the object via a free function when it's being deserialised? This way you decouple the object from the deserialiser.
There's an example of this in boost::serialization.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you didn't provide any constructor for the class, compiler auto generates default constructor(s). But once you'd provided at-least one of constructors then compiler will not provide any constructor even there is no more default constructor.